# Problem changing background image using Javascript

Tags: javascript, background-image

I'm trying to change the background image of a link when it is clicked via Javascript. I five tabs and when the user clicks on a tab, I want the background image of that tab to change to a plain white image. Where as the other four tabs should be changed to a grey image.

So my CSS is as follows:

```
.listingindex li a {
    background:url(../images/tabe-nomal.jpg) left top no-repeat;
    color:#333333;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:229px;
    padding:14px 0px 14px 10px;
}

.listingindex li a:hover {
    background:url(../images/tabe-over.jpg) left top no-repeat;
}
```

and my code looks like this:

```
<div class="listingindex">
                    <?php           
                    $catId = get_cat_id('featured');                
                    $childOf = 'child_of='.$catId;  
                    $subCats = get_categories($childOf);                

                    // Slice array so only 5 categories can be displayed.
                    $subCats = array_slice($subCats, 0, 5);

                    foreach ($subCats as $value) {
                        $subCatsStr .= $value->cat_ID.'|';                      
                    }                                               

                    foreach ($subCats as $subCat) {                         
                        ?>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a id="tab_<?=$subCat->cat_ID?>" href="javascript:toggle(<?=$subCat->cat_ID?>,'<?=$subCatsStr?>')"><?=$subCat->name?></a></li>
                        </ul>          

                        <ul id="thumbnails_<?=$subCat->cat_ID?>" class="listingarea">                           
                            <?php $query = new WP_Query('category_name='.$subCat->name.'&posts_per_page=9');
                                while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();?>
                                <li>                                                                                                            
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">                                      
                                        <?
                                        $id = $post->ID;                                        
                                        $filename = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxx/images/thumbnails/image_'.$id.'.jpg';                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                        if (file_exists($filename)) {
                                            ?><img src="<?php echo $templateDir; ?>/images/thumbnails/image_<?=$id;?>.jpg" alt="Image_<?=$id;?>" /><?                                           
                                        }else{                                          
                                            ?><img src="<?php echo $templateDir; ?>/images/thumbnails/no_image.jpg" alt="No Image" /><?
                                        }?>                                         
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>                                                                                                             
                        </ul>                                                                                   
                    <?}?>                 
                </div>
```

Lastly my JS looks like this:

```
function toggle(catID, subCatsStr) {
        document.getElementById('thumbnails_'+catID).style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('tab_'+catID).style.backgroundImage = "url(/images/tabe-over.jpg)";                     

        subCatsArr = subCatsStr.split('|');
        for (i = 0; i <= subCatsArr.length - 2; i++){
            if (subCatsArr[i] != catID){
                document.getElementById('thumbnails_'+subCatsArr[i]).style.display = "none";                
                document.getElementById('tab_'+catID).style.backgroundImage = "url(images/tabe-nomal.jpg) left top no-repeat";
            }           
        }           
    }
```

At the moment, this code simply removes the grey image (tabe-nomal.jpg) when a tab is clicked.

Any help appreciated.

Regards...

Comment: What is your directory structure like? In your css you're going up a directory `../images` but in the JS you're using `images` - is this correct?

Comment: Don't have time to read through it all, but one thing jumped out: You're trying to set multiple styles in your JavaScript code: `document.getElementById('tab_'+catID).style.backgroundImage = "url(images/tabe-nomal.jpg) left top no-repeat";` You have to set them individually (`backgroundImage`, `backgroundPosition`, `backgroundRepeat`, etc.).

Comment: T.J. Thanks I applied those changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem in the end I had to specify the full path name:

document.getElementById('tab_'+catID).style.backgroundImage = "url(http://www.xxxxxx.ie/xxxxxxx/wp-content/themes/xxxxxxx/images/tabe-over.jpg)";

Not sure why, but this solved the problem. Its a Wordpress theme so maybe this had something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your backgroundImage urls might not be correct -- try using the same path (../images/..) as in your initial css rule

Comment: Jib, I tried a number of different combinations but still no luck. My style sheet is in a CSS folder hence the '../images/xxxx.jpg'. The JS function is in my header file in the root folder so I would have thought the path was 'images/xxxx.jpg'. I tried '/images/xxxx.jpg' aswell but neither worked.

Comment: Doing it at the moment, but not entirely sure what to look out for...nothing out of the ordinary seems to be happening.

Comment: For one, you don't need to set document.getElementById('tab_'+catID).style.backgroundImage = "url(images/tabe-nomal.jpg) left top no-repeat"; in the loop.. that only only needs to happen once

Comment: Also, as T.J. Crowder mentioned above, it should only set backgroundImage = "url(images/tabe-nomal.jpg)";

Comment: Ok, when I specify the full image path everything works as it should:document.getElementById('tab_'+catID).style.backgroundImage = "url(http://www.xxxxxxx.com/xxxxxxx/wp-content/themes/xxxxxx/images/tabe-over.jpg)"; I'll do a bit of googling to figure out how to get the entire path name in JS so I don't have to hard code it. (NOTE: I've applied T.J's changes as well).